# Gif image in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin, I have to add a GIF image in my crossplatform app, I have read about the GifImageView (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GifImageView-Xamarin.Android), I know that I have to use it with custom renderer, but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: if you have experience with android , you can use Glide https://github.com/thanhdatbkhn/GlideXamarinBinding

Answer (score 2):

if you want easy implement to your gif with less configuration I advice you using Glide library , and its now supported via Nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glide.Xamarin/

how to use

```
Glide.With(context).Load("GifUrl")
                     .Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.placeholder)
                     .DiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.Source)
                     .Into(viewHolder.propertyImageView);
```

resource https://github.com/beraybentesen/glide-xamarin-android